# PHP fill up array holes

Tags: php, arrays

I've got an array with values stored per year, per week, coming from my database. The result might look like this:

```
Array
(
    [2018] => Array
        (
            [40] => 1
            [41] => 1
            [47] => 1
            [48] => 1
            [52] => 1
        )
    [2019] => Array
        (
            [1] => 1
            [2] => 1
            [3] => 1
            [4] => 1
        )
)


or


Array
(
    [2018] => Array
        (
            [48] => 1
            [49] => 1
        )
    [2019] => Array
        (
            [3] => 1
            [4] => 1
        )
)
```

As you can see there are weeks without data. I would like to fill up the array, so all weeks are there. Taking the last array as demo, the desired result would be:

```
Array
(
    [2018] => Array
        (
            [40] => 1
            [41] => 1
            [42] => 0 < added
            [43] => 0 < added
            [44] => 0 < added
            [45] => 0 < added
            [46] => 0 < added
            [47] => 1
            [48] => 1
            [49] => 0 < added
            [50] => 0 < added
            [51] => 0 < added
            [52] => 1
        )
    [2019] => Array
        (
            [1] => 1
            [2] => 1
            [3] => 1
            [4] => 1
        )
)
Array
(
    [2018] => Array
        (
            [48] => 1
            [49] => 1
            [50] => 0 < added
            [51] => 0 < added
            [52] => 0 < added
        )
    [2019] => Array
        (
            [1] => 1
            [2] => 
            [3] => 1
            [4] => 1
        )
)
```

So, the arrays should:

- fill up holes between two (not consecutively) numbers
- fill up the year array until the end if there is a next year
- fill up the first weeks of a new year if there is a previous year and no data in the first week

How can I achieve this?

Comment: What have you tried? Please also show samples of result that you're expecting

Comment: Do you know the expected weeks before hand? If so, then you can apply a default schema with array_merge

Comment: @Erwin, I've tried a variaty of complex codes where I know it can be done easier. Added the desired result

Comment: ok, so you just need to have no holes, but not to have all 52 weeks ?

Comment: @Murwa, no, the start and end can be different on every case.

Comment: @FrançoisHuppé exactly

Comment: Why does the second `2018` array was padded up to 52? 48 and 49 has no "holes"

Comment: how yo u decide 2018 will start with 48 or 40 and then 2019 with 1 week? Does date have something to do?

Comment: @Erwin, because there is a 2019 array, the 2018 should fill up till the end of the year

Comment: @ÐℛẲḰỮℒѦ, it comes from the database (`WEEK(datefield)` and `YEAR(datefield)`. Some weeks do have data, some don't

Comment: 3 and 4 weeks how they are 1,2,3,4? when first week starts with 3 in data?

Comment: When you will understand logic of start and end weeks, use something as `$template = array_fill(min(array_keys($arr[2018])), max(array_keys($arr[2018]))-min(array_keys($arr[2018]))+1, 0);

print_r(array_replace($template, $arr[2018]));`

Comment: @LinkinTED i'm not sure i understand your third requirement...

Comment: Those aren't values, they're keys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the most efficient way is to use the union operator. This should do it:

```
  <?php
    $data = array(
        "2018"=> array(
            "40" => 1,
            "41" => 1,
            "47" => 1,
            "48" => 1,
            "52" => 1
        ),
        "2019"=> array(
            "1" => 1,
            "2" => 1,
            "6" => 1,
            "7" => 1      
        )
    );

    foreach($data as $year=>$array){
        $keys = array_keys($array);
        $min = min($keys); $max = 52;
        if(!isset($data[$year+1])){
            $max = max($keys);
        }
        $data[$year] = $data[$year] + array_fill($min,$max-$min+1, 0);
        ksort($data[$year]);
    }
    print_r($data);
  ?>
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [2018] => Array
        (
            [40] => 1
            [41] => 1
            [42] => 0
            [43] => 0
            [44] => 0
            [45] => 0
            [46] => 0
            [47] => 1
            [48] => 1
            [49] => 0
            [50] => 0
            [51] => 0
            [52] => 1
        )

    [2019] => Array
        (
            [1] => 1
            [2] => 1
            [3] => 0
            [4] => 0
            [5] => 0
            [6] => 1
            [7] => 1
        )

)
```

Comment: @LinkinTED: I just saw your two other specification, let me adjust my answer !

Comment: Thank you, this answer helpt me in the right direction. I've tweaked it a bit   `foreach($data as $year => $weeks)
        {
         $min = (isset($data[$year-1])) ? 1 : min(array_keys($data[$year]));
         $max = (isset($data[$year+1])) ? 52 : max(array_keys($data[$year]));
         $template = array_fill($min, $max-$min+1, 0);
         $data[$year] = array_replace($template, $data[$year]);
        }`

Answer (score 2):

You can use a set of array functions such as [`array_fill()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-fill.php) and [`array_replace()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-replace.php) to achieve this.
See comments for the explanation

```
$array = [
    '2018' => [
        '40' => 1,
        '41' => 1,
        '47' => 1,
        '48' => 1,
        '52' => 1
    ],
    '2019' => [
        '3' => 1,
        '4' => 1
    ],
];

$result = []; // initialize result array

$years = array_keys($array); // Get given years
$first_year = min($years);   // Get first year
$last_year = max($years);    // Get last year

foreach ($array as $year => $value) { // Loop thru each year array
    $weeks = array_keys($value); // Get weeks
    $start = 1;                  // Set first week
    $weeknum = 52;               // Set number of weeks

    if ($year === $first_year) { // If first year, change number of weeks
        $start = min($weeks);    
        $weeknum -= $start - 1;  // number of weeks is 52 - the first week number - 1
    }

    if ($year === $last_year) {  // If last year, change number of weeks to last given week
        $weeknum = max($weeks);  // Weeks will be 1 - last given week
    }

    $result[$year] = array_replace(array_fill($start, $weeknum, 0), $value);
}

var_dump($result);
```

The first goal of this is to fill an array base on the year.

- If first year, create array with first given week to week 52
- If last year, create array with week 1 to last given week
- If somewhere in the middle, create array with week 1 to week 52

Then replace with your existing data array with same keys